# firebase service worker flailed to load first time but sucessfully load when refresh the page for second time

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-chrome, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am tying to implement firebase push notification in my nextjs project. The problem is I got this error when my page is initially loading

```
An error occurred while retrieving token.  DOMException: Failed to execute 'subscribe' on 'PushManager': Subscription failed - no active Service Worker
    at getPushSubscription (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/@firebase/messaging/dist/esm/index.esm2017.js:581:39)
    at async getTokenInternal (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/@firebase/messaging/dist/esm/index.esm2017.js:496:30
```

also not getting the token but when I reload the page it's working and getting the token. How to solve this problem? I added firebase-messaging-sw.js in my public directiory
and my firebase npm version  "firebase": "^10.7.1",

here my firebase-messaging-sw.js code:

```
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.10.1/firebase-app.js');
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.10.1/firebase-messaging.js');

firebase.initializeApp({
   my configration
});
 
 
const messaging = firebase.messaging();

messaging.onBackgroundMessage((payload) => {
 
  // Customize notification here
  const notificationTitle = payload.notification.title;
  const notificationOptions = {
    body:  payload.notification.body,
    icon: '/firebase-logo.png'
  };

  self.registration.showNotification(notificationTitle, notificationOptions);
});
```

also when tying to import model from another js file see this error for firebase-messaging-sw.js file

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
```

Answer (score 0):

I have also encountered the same issue below are the steps which helped to solved this issue

1. Import scripts in firebase-messaging-sw.js with compact-script
   // e.g.,
   importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/x.x.x/firebase-app-compat.js');
   importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/x.x.x/firebase-messaging-compat.js');
2. Register firebase-messaging-sw.js with scope '/firebase-cloud-messaging-push-scope' in _app.js

```
// inside the useEffect
    if ("serviceWorker" in navigator) {
      window.addEventListener("load", () => {
        // Register the service worker as soon as the app loads
        navigator.serviceWorker
          .register('/firebase-messaging-sw.js', { scope: '/firebase-cloud-messaging-push-scope' })
          .then((registration) => {
            console.log('Service Worker registered with scope:', registration.scope);
          })
          .catch((err) => {
            console.log('Service worker registration failed, error:', err);
          });
      });
    }
```

3. Create a function to ask for notification permission or modify this function

```
import { getMessaging, getToken } from 'firebase/messaging';
    import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app';
    
    const firebaseConfig = {
      apiKey: "",
      authDomain: "",
      projectId: "",
      storageBucket: "",
      messagingSenderId: "",
      appId: "",
      measurementId: ""
    };
    
    // Initialize Firebase
    export const firebaseApp = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

export const askUserForNotificationPermission = async () => {
  if (typeof window !== 'undefined' && 'serviceWorker' in navigator) {
    const messaging = getMessaging(firebaseApp);
    const permission = await Notification.requestPermission();
    if (permission === "granted") {
      const currentToken = await getToken(messaging, {
        vapidKey: PUBLIC_VAPID_KEY
      });
      if (currentToken) {
        console.log(":::currentToken", currentToken);
      } else {
        console.log('No registration token available. Request permission to generate one.');
      }
    } else {
      console.warn("Notification permission DENIED");
    }
  }
}
```

Hope,this would solve the issue :)